# Regex usage in web scraping

Tags: html, regex

Here's the regex101 link to my case: https://regex101.com/r/XKNQoR/1

I'm using the following Regex in my scraping procedure to extract link from HTML code.

```
(https\:\/\/cdn\.[a-zA-Z0-9`~!@#$%^&*,?;:=+-\.\/\-]+)
```

This extracts the link as follows:

```
https://cdn.example.net/embed/%20Courses/1.%20After%20effects?expires=15911919&amp;signature=e57d02a8f3f1971a6​
```

What can I add to the expression to make it extract the link without the `&amp=...` parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an updated regex, inserting an extra capture group:
https://regex101.com/r/XKNQoR/2
Together with substitution ("amp" removed): https://regex101.com/r/XKNQoR/3

This produces the following link, which you can see in the bottom of the previous linked page:

https://cdn.example.net/embed/%20Courses/1.%20After%20effects?expires=15911919&;signature=e57d02a8f3f1971a6

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your quick reply. It worked but I now have one more problem:
It's extracting all the string/text after the link

Comment: Or, more general, using (https\:\/\/cdn\.[a-zA-Z0-9`~!@#$%^&*,?;:=+-\.\/\-]+)amp(;signature=[a-z0-9]+)$       https://regex101.com/r/XKNQoR/5

Comment: Man! Thank you tons for your help! This is working flawlessly.

Comment: I am very happy to hear that :)